# Apache server on Local Network issues

Tags: php, apache

i want to access my website locally so i used Apache Server on one computer and connect it to LAN. when i access the computer1 IP from Computer2 it works fine even my login page is appearing but i enter username and password it show the error: Unable to Connect

[image: View error message]

[image: login page]

Comment: If your server is on another machine, the browser should not be trying to connect to localhost. Without looking at your login page, it's not possible to guess why that is. But if the word 'localhost' appears anywhere in your code, you've found your problem.

Comment: i have uploaded picture of login page as well kindly see that picture and tell me whats the issue

Comment: Sorry for the slow reply. I should have said "without looking at the code for your login page", but hopefully you have already fixed the problem.

Comment: no i have still this issue. localhost only appers when i entered username and password.

Comment: is it possible that Database is not connecting on other machine???